# use first token in a string to create separate array lists, second token will

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm writing Java code. I have files that looks like:

1. President and Vice-President ==> Fred Flinestone(P)
2. US Senate ==> Louise Moon (P)
3. Proposition #1 ==> Yes
4. Amendment #1 ==> Decline

I am trying to separate the different contest (President and Vice-President, US Senate, etc.) from the "voter's choice" (Alvin Boone..., Louise, etc) line by line. I want to use the first token to create an array list and the second token to be added to the corresponding array list.

I hope I am not over my head with this as I am a new Java programmer but all help is appreciated. So far I have.

```
public void go () {
  getContest();
}

void getContest() {
  // reading file and call the addContest() method for each line/
  try {
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
      addContest(line);
    }
  }
}

void addContest (String lineToParse) {
  String[] tokens = lineToParse.split(">");

  // somehow this will add contests to
  // its own array 0 is the first part of split
  contestList.add(tokens[0]);
}
```

I hope I am not asking for too much but if I can find out how to create the array list I am sure I can put second token in the corresponding array. Thank you!

Comment: Is this homework?  If so, please add the homework tag

Comment: I will accept any help...even if its a website that tells me how to use a for loop with an array..this is not for any grade..

Comment: Cool; what's it for? You'd really be better off using a list to avoid having to know, or guess, the number of elements. Or a map keyed by the contest, holding lists of each's "entries". The data you show makes it difficult to guess what you actually need; by telling us what the requirements are, and where they came from, you make it easier for us to guess.

Comment: I was always told you learn by doing. I write programs I come up with and I have been on the student government board so...Trying to make a tally machine..which is the reason why I chose using an array list. Then the 2nd token would be used to tally up the votes. I just started this code an ran into this problem. What else could I provide to help?

Comment: I still think a map is your best bet: each "prefix" (like "US Senate") is a key. As you encounter that prefix, make sure that map entry has its own list, and add the "suffix" (like "Louise Moon") to that list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you would probably be better served by a map.  The first element is the key, and the second element the value.

```
ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    lines.add(line);
}
HashMap<String, String> votes = new HashMap<String, String>();
for(String line: lines) {
    String[] terms = line.split(">");
    votes.put(terms[0], terms[1]);
}
```

Comment: Im still working on this and I am learning to read code as well..so can you tell me..regarding the "lines" in the code above..it needs to will be a local String variable? eclipse wants me to add it as an object.

Comment: Updated to demonstrate one way to do this.  You could also just use the while loop directly and eliminate the lines variable.